# CSS background image only behind the top x pixels of screen; below (and behind if image at top is transparent) solid color

Tags: html, css

How can I create a CSS background consisting of an image covering the top x pixels of the body and a solid color or gradient below (also spanning behind the top bg picture if it is transparent)?

A gradient can be stacked placed on top of a solid color, so that the gradient fills the entire height of the screen. How can I change the gradient to a picture and only make it x pixels high?

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(239,237,224,1) 30%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%) top/100% 100vh no-repeat rgba(239,237,224,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo element for the image:

```css
body {
  min-height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
  background:linear-gradient(red,blue);
}
body::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:100px; /* update this */
  inset: 0 0 auto;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/800/600) center/cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple background images - with a mixture of actual images and gradient images.

The first image in the list is rendered on top of the others and so on down the list. You can set the size and positioning and repetition of each separately or together.

In this snippet the individual settings are separated out to make it clearer what is going on:

```css
.bg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew6J2.png), linear-gradient(to bottom, red,blue);
  background-size: 30vw auto, 100% 100%;
  background-position: center top, 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```